# Can't edit or create new nodes

Tags: nodes, wysiwyg

I've struck a problem that I can't explain and have no idea how to fix.

The symptoms of the problem are that clicking the *Save* button causes the page to refresh back to its original state. The *Preview* button behaves the same way.

The site is running *drupal 7.22*. It was working fine a few weeks ago but I can no longer edit or create nodes. To the best of my knowledge, nothing has changed by me.

I looked at the logs and there was no obvious errors. I noticed that *Ckeditor* was upset that `ckeditor.js` has disappeared from its correct location. This seemed unlikely but it wasn't there. I disabled *Ckeditor*.

Still no luck. The *edit* and *add* forms fail silently. This applies to as well as user's other content.

I don't think it's a database problem. For example, I can *block/unblock* user accounts from the list *UI* but not from the *edit user* page. I can perform module updates including *DB updates*.

Anyone have any thoughts how I can resolve this problem? All suggestions gratefully accepted.

Many thanks.

Steve.

Comment: You could try to update your core to see if that fixes anything…

Comment: have you changed any of the javascript libraries like jquery? are you seeing any errors in the js console?

Comment: As an aside, version 7.22 is extremely vulnerable to a particularly nasty SQL injection attack.  If your site is live on the internet then there's a very good chance that it has already been hacked.  You should update immediately and investigate whether it has been hacked and take remedial action.  You can find more information at https://www.drupal.org/node/2357241, http://www.js.geek.nz/blog/your-drupal-website-has-backdoor

Comment: This was one of the (many) symptoms reported when Drupalgeddon was around - you need to upgrade to at least 7.32 immediately, then get someone to audit your server to see if you've been hacked. Hopefully you haven't, but without knowing it's kind of futile to guess what could be wrong. In such an old and insecure site the trouble could be coming from a lot of different places

Comment: Many thanks to you all. I was aware of the Drupageddon attack, and applied the patch within a few hours of the announcement. I thought I'd got away with it.